# Graphic output using auto-pst-pdf differs from dvips-ps2pdf

Tags: eps, dvips, auto-pst-pdf, ps2pdf

I want to insert some eps-files with a gray frame to represent the original page margin inside my document. When compiling a document with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` I get the desired output with no additional white frame and no blank page inserted before the second included eps file.

Using `auto-pst-pdf` the first graphic gets a white frame, clearly visible on the left and right, which is not present in the original file. Additionally, a blank page is inserted before the second graphic, but no Overfull hbox or vbox warning is issued. (The same graphics as pdf files give the desired output, as well, irrespective of utilization of epstopdf or as externally produced pdfs).

**Edit:** removed `\noindent` following David Carlisle's advice.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,DIV=calc,fleqn,captions=tableheading,bibliography=totoc,parskip=off,numbers=noenddot,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=3.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=8mm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm,includeheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.77cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2cm}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.2pt}
    \clearpage
    \begin{center}
        {\color{lightgray}\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth,trim=4 4 4 4]{TEST-Artikel}}}
    \end{center}

%   \clearpage
    \begin{center}
        {\color{lightgray}\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth,trim=4 4 4 4]{TEST-SI}}}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Removing `\clearpage` before the second graphic or scaling it down to `0.97\textwidth` solves the problem with the blank page, but I did not find a satisfying solution to get rid of the white frame.

**Edit:** Removing `\clearpage` before the second graphic only removes the blank page betwenn the two types of graphics, but for more than one TEST-SI graphics there is still a blank page inserted after the first TEST-SI.

Does `auto-pst-pdf` handle the files in a different way than the "normal" `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` mode? Do I need any other optional arguments to make it work?
Note that `crop=on` removes too much of the white space in the second graphic and the impression of a scaled page inserted into the document is lost.

**Additional Information:** The white space seems to be added after the graphic is processed, seemingly when the pdf is placed. In the *FILENAME-pics.pdf* of `auto-pst-pdf` everything looks normal and all optional arguments of `\includegraphics` (*scaling*, *trimming*, setting the *bounding box*) are processed, before the white frame is added. Explizit options `frame=false` and `innerframe=false` have no effect.

**dvips-ps2pdf Output**

[image: dvips-ps2pdf-1]
[image: dvips-ps2pdf-2]

**auto-pst-pdf Output**

[image: auto-pst-pdf-1]
[image: auto-pst-pdf-2]
[image: auto-pst-pdf-3]

**png Versions of eps Files**

[image: png-version of TEST-Artikel]
[image: png-version of TEST-SI]

Comment: Probably, if you convert to pdf by hand using `pst-pdf`, you'll have control on the way its is cropped. This being said, if the real graphic in the header is this blue strip, it is easy to obtain it in pure latex, using `eso-pic`.

Comment: you are loading the auto-pst-pdf package but you don't appear to be using pstricks at all, so you don't need to load the package do you? Also but probably unrelated `\noindent\begin{center}` does nothing useful you should delete the `\noindent`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, in the original document I am using chemnum, so I need auto-pst-pdf, but I did not include it, as it is not relevant for this special case. Even though unrelated, I am always happy to learn and improve my style.

Comment: @Bernard In the original document I include about 60 pages via loop, so any automatic solution is highly appreciated.